# Computing variance and co variance in a data statement

Tags: function, math, sas, covariance, variance

I have 8 columns in my dataset, and I would like to run a data statement in SAS such as:

(this is some pseudocode)

```
data mynewset;
set myoldset;
variance1 = Variance(column1,column2,column3,column4);
variance2 = Variance(column5,column6,column7,column8);
covariance = Covariance(<column1,column2,column3,column4>,<column5,column6,column7,column8>);
run;
```

How can I setup this Var and Covar functions in SAS ? (btw I'm not interested in a proc)

FYI - mathematical formulas are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Comment: You want the entire-column variance, or just the variance of those 4 values present in that one row of data?  If you want the former, you're going to have to explain in a lot more detail why you don't want to use a PROC, as that's an easy way to do it, and generally the correct way.

Comment: I want the variance of the 4 values in the row. I don't want to use a proc because it is a big statement and I compute variance and covariance of multiple combination of 4 columns... but maybe I can adapt How would you write the proc statement then? Thanks!

Comment: So. variance(5,6,8,14); as if you'd typed it into excel?

Comment: My dataset and the wanted outcome: row_id column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 var1 var2 
1 5 2 8 3 3 0 10 8 5.25 20.91666667 
2 10 4 6 7 6 1 4 4 4.6875 4.25

Comment: Please edit that into the question, it's too hard to read comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For row-wise variance (ie, the variance of several values in a row), there is a function, `VAR`, which will compute that for you.

```
var_x = var(of x1-x4);
```

for example would compute the variance of x1,x2,x3,x4.

There is not a similar covariance function; you would need to compute that directly from the formula, ie,

```
cov(x,y) = sum((X-xmean)*(Y-ymean) / N
```

You could do that using an array and a `do` loop.